# Twilio Empty Response from VB.net HTTPListener

Tags: vb.net, twilio, response, httplistener

I'm using an HTTPListener in VB.net to handle the initial contact from a new Twilio SMS. Everything works fine except that I get a retrieval error. The documentation demands that I send back either empty TwiML Response tags, or a 200 status. I have tried a dozen different combinations including:

```vb
Dim buffer = System.Text.Encoding.[Default].GetBytes("http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=%3CResponse%3E%3C%2FResponse%3E")

context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
context.Response.StatusCode = CInt(HttpStatusCode.OK)
context.Response.OutputStream.Close()
```

.

```
    Dim buffer = System.Text.Encoding.[Default].GetBytes("<Response></Response")

context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
context.Response.StatusCode = CInt(HttpStatusCode.OK)
context.Response.OutputStream.Close()
```

.

```
    Dim buffer = System.Text.Encoding.[Default].GetBytes("<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><Response></Response>")

context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
context.Response.StatusCode = CInt(HttpStatusCode.OK)
context.Response.OutputStream.Close()
```

I took my FallbackURL's php code which works as a .php file, and made it as a string:

```
Dim buffer = System.Text.Encoding.[Default].GetBytes("<?php" & vbCrLf & "header(""content-type Text/ Xml"");" & vbCrLf & "echo ""<?xml version=\""1.0\"" encoding=\""UTF-8\""?>\n"";" & vbCrLf & "?>" & vbCrLf & "<Response></Response>")

context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
context.Response.StatusCode = CInt(HttpStatusCode.OK)
context.Response.OutputStream.Close()
```

I tried using an actual HTML page that I used for testing. All of these generate a receipt failure error.

What is the correct format to respond with an acknowledgment of receipt in VB?

Here is the entire Function code for reference:

```
   Dim ws = New SimpleWebServer("http://*:8081/Orders/")
    AddHandler ws.RequestReceived, Function(sender, context)

                                       Dim Content As String = String.Empty
                                       Dim request As HttpListenerRequest = context.Request
                                       Dim body As Stream = request.InputStream
                                       Dim encoding1 As System.Text.Encoding = request.ContentEncoding
                                       Dim reader1 As New StreamReader(body, encoding1)
                                       Content = reader1.ReadToEnd

                                       Try
                                           Dim TextParameterParse() As String = Content.Split("&")
                                           Dim TextKeyValue As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

                                           For Each Parameter As String In TextParameterParse
                                               Dim KeyValueParse() As String = Parameter.Split("=")
                                               TextKeyValue.Add(KeyValueParse(0), KeyValueParse(1))
                                           Next

                                           ActionIncoming(Long.Parse(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(TextKeyValue.Item("From"))), HttpUtility.UrlDecode(TextKeyValue.Item("Body")))
                                       Catch ex As exception

                                       End Try

'This is where the response code above is placed.
                                       Return 1
                                   End Function
```

Comment: Are you running this locally on your own machine? What URL have you given to Twilio to make a request to?

Comment: I have given the IP address of my home network, as well as the target destination where my program is launched. In both locations, the SMS messages are successfully delivered, however it is reported as failed.

Comment: @MikeGauer can you look at your Twilio debugger and post the specific HTTP errors Twilio is logging when it tries to call the URL of your application?  https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/debugger

Comment: @DevinRader Error 11200

Comment: Thats Twilios way of telling you that it had a problem making the request to the URL that you've supplied.  The log should also tell you which HTTP status code got returned and if there was any content like a stack trace returned that will be logged as well.  If you use a tool like Fiddler to make the POST request to the URL what get returned?  Also, is the IP you've configured a publicly accessible IP?